# How to receive form data on the server side in an Angular/Spring Boot application?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, rest, spring-boot

I have an application based on Spring Boot and Angular. There, I have this form:

```
<form name="create-project">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="project.name"
               placeholder="Project name">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"
                ng-click="createProject(project)">Create project</button>
      </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

`createProject` is defined in the controller.

```
[...]
.controller('projects', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/resource/').success(function(data) {
        $scope.greeting = data;
    });
    $scope.createProject = function(project) {
        console.log("createProject called on the client side, project name: " +
            project.name);
        $http.post('/createProject', {name: project.name}).success(function(){
            console.log("createProject called successfully");
        });
    }
});
```

On the server side, I have following method for handling `createProject` requests:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class MyApplication {
    [...]
    @RequestMapping(value="/createProject", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String createProject(final String name) {
        System.out.println("createProject, server side, name: " + name);
        return "";
    }   
}
```

When I run the application, enter some text into the project name field and press the *Create project* button, following things happen:

1. I see the log message on the client side (`createProject called on the client side, project name:`) with the correct project name.
2. In the server logs I see `createProject, server side, name: null`.

The entered project name either isn't passed to the server, or it doesn't accept it.

How can I fix it, i. e. make sure that I can access the entered project name in the method `MyApplication.createProject`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JavaScript code looks okay to me. I think you need to add `@RequestBody` to your `createProject()`. At the moment it is checking the url for a value for name. For example /createProject?name=John. What you are doing instead is you are specifying it in the request body. That's why the name is null.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class MyApplication {
    [...]
    @RequestMapping(value="/createProject", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String createProject(@RequestBody final String name) {
        System.out.println("createProject, server side, name: " + name);
        return "";
    }   
}
```